# How to convert minutes into HH:MM:SS formate in sql server

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

I am having a column in my sql server database table with datatype bigint.
Now i need to convert this column into HH:MM:SS formate.
For this i use this command

```
SELECT cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MS,SUM(mFld),0),8) as Time) FROM tblm
```

But this command doesn't show right time duration.
For right time duration i use this command

```
SELECT rtrim(LTRIM(cast((mFld/(60*60)) as char)))+':' +rtrim(LTRIM(cast((mFld%(60*60))/(60)as char)))+':'+rtrim(LTRIM(cast(((mFld%(60*60))%(60)) as char))) FROM tblm
```

This command shows right result.But resulted data type is varchar.How can i convert this column in to time column with same result.

### Example

```
DECLARE @minites bigint;
SET @minites = 5200020;
SELECT rtrim(LTRIM(cast((@minites/(60*60)) as char)))+':' +rtrim(LTRIM(cast((@minites%(60*60))/(60)as char)))+':'+rtrim(LTRIM(cast(((@minites%(60*60))%(60)) as char)))
SELECT cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MS,SUM(@minites),0),8) as Time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i convert this column in to time column with same result.

You can't. Time has the range `00:00:00.0000000` to `23:59:59.9999999`.

[time (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

Comment: Ok.you mean to say we can not store time more then 24 hour in Time field.